# Change sequence order of table

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table containing the specific categories a restaurant can have in it's menu (e.g: Appetizers, Drinks, main course, deserts,...)

Example data for **menu_restaurant_category**:

```
+----+------------+-------------+----------+
| ID | restaurant | category    | sequence |
+----+------------+-------------+----------+
| 11 |         35 | MAIN COURSE |        1 |
| 12 |         35 | DESERTS     |        2 |
| 13 |         35 | DRINKS      |        3 |
| 14 |         35 | APPETIZERS  |        4 |
+----+------------+-------------+----------+
```

I want to allow the admin to choose the order in which the categories will be displayed on the menu.
The row with the highest number in the column `sequence` gets displayed first.

Now: Let's say I click the up-button for ID 11.
ID 11 should get the sequence-number 2, and ID 12 should get the sequence number one. The opposite should happen when the down-button is clicked.

How would I in SQL do this?

- I'd somehow need to get the following row in the order.
- And swap the values of the sequence-columns between those two rows.

Comment: Sounds like two `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: Does the only operation is to swap sequence values for **two adjacent** rows?

Comment: What is precise MySQL version? Does the `sequence` column is defined as UNIQUE? Does the values in this column are consecutive?

Answer (score 0):

Use step 10 for sequence value. That allows to insert value between any two items.
Renumerate a sequence after reordering.
Wrap it all in the stored routine.

```
 UPDATE menu_restaurant_category  
    SET sequence = sequence + 10 + 1 -- one row down and a bit more
  WHERE ID = xxxxx;                  -- SP parameter 

 UPDATE menu_restaurant_category  
    SET sequence = @seq := @seq + 10 -- UDV counter
  WHERE (@seq := 0) = 0              -- UDV initialization
  ORDER BY sequence ASC;
```